# What are the Adobe standards used for digital signature?

Tags: certificate, adobe, digital-signature, electronic-signature

I am a novice programmer who is implementing a digital signature for a PDF doc. I want to know the standards used in the industry to sign and verify the document.

A stepwise approach from key generation to verification of document works for me.

Comment: This library in nodejs is the closest thing I can find to a valid implementation:

https://github.com/vbuch/node-signpdf#readme

Still doesn't discuss actually system or certificate requirements that would actually help ensure the signature is legally binding

Answer (score 0):

There are ISO standards and RFCs for digital signatures.

But the above have many many options. So the real question is "which profile for digital signatures is most recommended?" The answer is [PAdES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAdES). It is supported and used by Adobe, DocuSign, and all of the significant players.

Comment: I recently was working on trying to build a custom e-signature component and it seems like no one has published a practical guide to implementing PAdES. 

I found the signing certificate situation itself very confusing (asked this question but never got any response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62551037/how-do-e-signature-companies-create-valid-digital-signatures).